# Error popup position in td from table inside div overflow auto

Tags: html, css, html-table, position

I need help to resolve a issue in Chrome and IE. Effectively, in Mozilla it works fine!
Let me explain:
I got a Div "overflow" containing a Table.
In this table I generate dynamically tr and td. 
Each tr have 2 td. 
Each td contains UserControl ASP.Net wich are a div containing
a div "popup" display none and some other element to display.

```
<div class="overflow">
  <table class="table_planning">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div id="divCellule" runat="server" onmouseover="ShowInfoBulle(this);" onmouseout="HideInfoBulle(this);">
                <div class="infobulle" id="infobulle">
                </div>
                some control... (Not the problem)
             </div>             
         </td>
         <td>
             <-- ANOTHER UC Correctly Displayed -->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
             ...
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overflow {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.table_planning .infobulle {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 280px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #464241;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: -10px 0 0 70px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function ShowInfoBulle(e) {
        $(e).find('#infobulle').show();
    }

    function HideInfoBulle(e) {
        $(e).find('#infobulle').hide();
    }
```

On hover of the div container, I show the div popup!
But when my table is scrolled, popup position (absolute) is not following the scroll position (IE and Chrome only - works fine in Firefox).

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/q57zv7oo/6)

Example of bug in IE or Chrome:

[image]

Example of correct display in FireFox:

[image]

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. This link http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve will help you writing a complete question that will allow the community to help you.

Comment: Hello, Luca thanks for replied but i don't understand why my post is not understandable? ;)

Comment: your post is *incomplete* - you should add a working example that replicates your problem; the link I've provided can help you understanding what steps to take. It is impossible for the community to help you debugging your issue without all the shortest relevant code.

Comment: Hi, thank for replied. I'll try to create a fiddle JS but i'm not sure it's an obligation to understand the problem. I know it's better to try some things... See you soon i hope

Comment: Sorry for late! I got a Fiddle witch work in FF and not in chrome reproducing the bug: https://jsfiddle.net/q57zv7oo/6/

Answer (score 0):

add `position: relative` and `overflow: visible` to `.table_planning tr td.nom`

```
.table_planning tr td.nom {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        /* your other styles */
}
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/q57zv7oo/7/)

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't test in IE, but I believe it will work fine. I've tested FF and Chrome and it looks good. Hope that helps!